# Memory VS data computer program

Tags: java, arrays, list, variables, memory

I guess this is a beginners theoretical question: 
I'm thinking of a program that will store data "internally" rather than processing data with a file as source. Data is input to the program by the user and the output is to stay "within" the program (does that make sense??). 
I'm using 1 array of size 12 to input unlimited amount of string tokens from user. 
I plan to perform searching and sorting operations mostly.

As the container grows, does the program process output of the data to itself the same way it would on a file external to the program?
I guess the real question is : is it better to store output to the external file and process it from there or is better to keep the data of the program?
For memory and speed purposes is an array better to use or are there better containers which I should use?

I'm sure I'd find an answer on a book but I just wanted to get your opinions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to store data only in memory. Java provides a number of different containers to handle the details of this for you. Holding data in memory is often easier than a file because

- It is much faster to access the data
- You can jump around in the data easily
- You can more easily build complex structures in memory than you can on disk

It is possible, if you are dealing with a very large amount of data, to exceed the size that can be reasonably held in memory. For a typical desktop computer of today, that size would probably be a few gigabytes.